# How to prevent Jquery append more than once

Tags: jquery, append, email-validation

I have some jQuery that checks if the user inputted a correct email address. The user can then go back and change his/her email if it is not valid. However, my code will result in the same error messege twice because the error keeps getting appended inside my `errors` div. How can I change this to only allow the error to be appended once? I also would like to remove the error if the `email` variable is `true`. There are also other validation errors being placed in this div.

jQuery:

```
var email = $('#email').val();
email = validateEmail(email);
if (email = "false") {
    $('#errors').append("<p>Please enter a valid email</p>");
}
```

`validateEmail` will return either `true` or `false` depending on whether the email is valid.

Comment: why re-invent the wheel. jQuery can validate e-mails for you http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var email = $('#email').val();
email = validateEmail(email);
if (email == "false"){
      $('#email_error').remove();
      $('#errors').append("<p id='email_error'>Please enter a valid email</p>");
}
```

Comment: i should have mentioned that i have other errors in this div too so .html would probably erase the other errors

Comment: thanks but it didnt work.  i got it to work using ID instead of class and just using `$('#email_error').remove();`

Comment: I've modified your answer a bit to remove the whole appended DIV. See below.

Answer (score 4):

when u append the email error, specity it with a class "**emailerror**",

```
$('#errors').append("<p class="emailerror">Please enter a valid email</p>");
```

but before append, just remove that error which have class "emailerror"

```
var email = $('#email').val();
email = validateEmail(email);
if (email = "false"){
    $('#errors .emailerror').remove();
    $('#errors').append("<p class="emailerror">Please enter a valid email</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try clearing the value before appending new information, ie new errors:

```
$('#errors').val('');
```

Comment: i cant clear errors because there may be other errors in there from other form elements

Answer (score 1):

Use `html()` or `text()` to set the content of the errors `div`:

```
$('#errors').html("<p>Please enter a valid email</p>");
```

And to not display anything when `email` is `true`, add an `else` to your `if` statement:

```
if (email === "false"){
    $("#errors").html("<p>Please enter a valid email</p>");
} else {
    $("#errors").html("");
}
```

Also note that I used `===` instead of `=`. This is because using a single equals sign (`=`) will just set the variable `email` to `false` and not actually check for equality.

Comment: i should have mentioned that i have other errors in this div too so .html would probably erase the other errors

Comment: all of my errors go into this one div so that users can see all their form errors in one place. (this is a sign up page)  is this not a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

More appropriate way is to remove all the appended code from DOM tree:

**Try this**:

```
var email = $('#email').val();
email = validateEmail(email);
if (email == "false"){
      $('#email_error').parent().remove();
      $('#errors').append("<p id='email_error'>Please enter a valid email</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is add a `$('.appended').remove()` right after your conditional, then in the text you are appending, use a `p` tag and add a `class="appended"` it works well